# How to create icosohedral cluster in Lammps?

Tags: lammps

I know how to create cube, cylinder and sphere shapes in Lammps, but I don't know how to create an icosahedral cluster in Lammps.
Does anybody know about it?

Comment: Please show previous work before posting this kind of question. (Like show how you think the 20-cluster can be created)

Comment: in some simulations,matlab code was used to create 20-cluster.but i want to know how to create it with lammps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to search the Lammps molecular topology.

https://docs.lammps.org/molecule.html

I would make custom groups of atoms/molecules with different bonds, angles...
In order to aproximate the cosahedral cluster.

Here is a piece of the molecule documentation:

```
N atoms = # of atoms N in molecule, default = 0

Nb bonds = # of bonds Nb in molecule, default = 0

Na angles = # of angles Na in molecule, default = 0

Nd dihedrals = # of dihedrals Nd in molecule, default = 0

Ni impropers = # of impropers Ni in molecule, default = 0

Nf fragments = # of fragments in molecule, default = 0

Mtotal mass = total mass of molecule

Xc Yc Zc com = coordinates of center-of-mass of molecule

Ixx Iyy Izz Ixy Ixz Iyz inertia = 6 components of inertia tensor of molecule
```

I hope my info help you. I'm new at Lammps as well.